# html5 canvas text not the specified size

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, font-size

When I specify the HTML5 canvas font as "50px Arial", I'd expect that every uppercase letter would have a height of 50 pixels. However, I'm getting a height of 35 pixels. I couldn't find anything at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/font). What am I missing?

I'm using Firefox Quantum 69.0 (64-bit), with layout.css.devPixelsPerPx property set to 1.

```js
var cnv = document.getElementById('cnv');
cnv.width = 300;
cnv.height = 200;
var ctx = cnv.getContext('2d');
ctx.font = '50px Arial';
ctx.fillText('Test',100,100);
```

```css
canvas {
  background-color:green;
  width: 300px;
  height:200px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id='cnv'></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

I doubled up your "Test" text exactly 50 pixels below the original, then superimposed a 50x50 image over the text and guess what?

[image]

Turns out `ctx.font` actually [defines line height in pixels.](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_font.asp) Or at least, there is no distinction made between controlling line height and font size. I can't find a good explanation exactly as to why.

Using `pt` in place of `px` to style your font gives you something much, much closer to what you want.

Comment: How exactly did you doubled it up?

Comment: @Rodrigo Just repeat the code and change the coordinates. In this case,  `ctx.font = '50px Arial';
ctx.fillText('Test',100,150);`

Comment: Then it wasn't `ctx.font` but your coordinates that defined the line height.

Comment: I guess that wasn't the best way to show what I was trying to say. The line height is still defined by the `font` setting. If you want your letters to truly be an absolute size (and not just within a 50px line) then use `pt` instead of `px` when defining font size. Because as you say, a "50px" font only takes up around 35px.

Comment: I've read about `pt` and how it's based on an arbitrary fraction of an inch (1/72). My site is going to produce a PNG (thus measured in pixels). Although `50 pt` gave me a better approximation (uppercase 46 pixels high), I wonder if that's the way to go, instead of understanding the rationale behind `px`.